# I want to echo php text but not between ()

Tags: php

I want to echo php text but not between (). Some thing like this =

```
<?php
$text = "Barry(male)";
echo $text;
?>
```

output =
Barry

How can i do this?

Comment: Can you rerphrase / or clarify what it is you actually want please..?

Comment: @Stuart it seems they need to remove what's between the parentheses and the parentheses themselves.

Comment: Hmmm.... Split the incoming string on "(", and output the first element of the array you end up with...

Comment: Where does the data come from? You should fix it there instead so that you have the different properties in an array or an object.

Comment: Please add the rules for the text input. Is the bracketed text always at the end? Are nested brackets possible?

Comment: You should add more details to the question. For example, where does the data come from and can it be fixed there? Otherwise, a simple `substr` could do the job or regular expression (depending on the actual requirements).

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) to substitute whatever is between parenthes (and the parentheses themselves) with an empty string. Like this:

```
<?php
    $text = "Barry(male)";
    echo preg_replace('#\(.*\)#', '', $text);
?>
```

Please note: since you didn't specify your string format, I'm assuming that the parenthesized text appears just once in the string and that there aren't nested parenthes. Otherwise, this doesn't work as expected.

Comment: Will this work with *"Barry(male) likes Marry(female)"*, or return *"Barry"*?

Comment: Warning:  preg_replace(): Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash

Comment: @PhilippMaurer it will output "Barry likes Marry" with your example string

Comment: @Cashbee I don't think so, you need non-greedy matching for that.

Comment: @jeroen Oops yes you're right! Also I want to point out that this solution struggles with nested Braces. I know, OP didn't specify the rules for the input string, but IMO it is worth mentioning.

Comment: @Cashbee I agree, though I also think that this is completely the wrong place to solve a problem that you should not have in the first place. Probably :-)

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
$text = "Barry(male)";
$split = explode("(", $text);

echo $split[0];
// "Barry"
```

Comment: This solution assumes, that the brackets are always at the end of the text.

Comment: while this works for that explicit example, there are many things that this solution won't catch, what about text after the brackets for exxample? To be fair, OP didnt specify these things..

Comment: Based on the question it's implied that these parens are always there. 
OP will need to give further examples of the input string.